# How to efficiently draw multiple primitives in cocos2d-iphone?

Tags: opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone

I'm playing around with cocos2d-iphone and it looks great!

But i want to for each update draw another circle on screen, this lowers the framerate very fast!
Can i draw multiple primitives a somewhat faster way?

This is the code i currently us

```
-(void) draw
{
    glLineWidth(1);
    glColor4ub(100,100,255,0);
    float angle = 0;
    float radius = 10.0f;
    int numSegments = 10;
    bool drawLineToCenter = NO;

    NSInteger point;
    for (point=0;point < [points count];point++)
    {
        ccDrawCircle([[points objectAtIndex:point] CGPointValue], radius, angle, numSegments, drawLineToCenter);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use sprites instead of primitives. Then you can use CCSpriteBatchNode.

The primitive draw methods of cocos2d are mainly there for debugging purposes, not to make up your game art. Primarily they are not batched operations, which means every new primitive you draw will issue a draw call. And that's expensive.